# Order by two meta values - one is a number and the other is text

Tags: order, meta-value

Based on multiple searches, this is the code I'm trying to sort by two different meta key values.

```
'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'listing_order' => array(
            'key' => 'atsc_bod_listing_order',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'key' => 'atsc_bod_last_name',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'listing_order' => 'ASC',
        'last_name' => 'ASC',
),
```

I want to first sort by a numerical value and then if the numerical values are the same, sort by last name.  This code returns no results. I'm think it has something to do with not knowing if the sort field is 'meta_value_num' or 'meta_value' but I'm not sure how/where to add that information.

Here is the full code that includes the suggestion below.

```
<?php
        $args = array (
        'post_type'         => 'atsc_bod',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_status'       => 'publish',



            'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    'listing_order' => array(
                        'key' => 'atsc_bod_listing_order',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                    ),
                    'last_name' => array(
                        'key' => 'atsc_bod_last_name',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                    ), 
                ),
                'orderby' => array( 
                    'listing_order' => 'ASC',
                    'last_name' => 'ASC',
            ),



        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `atsc_bod_listing_order` meta is a number, then you should set the [`type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) argument to `NUMERIC` like so, so that the meta value is casted as a number which then gives you the correct numerical sorting:

```php
'listing_order' => array(
    'key'     => 'atsc_bod_listing_order',
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
),
```

Comment: I still get no results - not an error, just the query returns no results.   My SQL is a bit rusty but this seems counter intuitive "'relation' => 'AND',". I tried it without and got an error message.  Looking at the link you shared, doesn't mention anything about sorting.  This code seems geared towards filtering down content, not sort it.

Comment: Well, the `orderby` argument is the one that sets the sort criteria, but whether MySQL will sort the meta/value as a number or not, depends on the `type` argument - if it's not set, then the value will by default be sorted as a string, so `1, 2, 10, 3` would become `1, 10, 2, 3` instead of `1, 2, 3, 10` when the value *is a number or **casted/treated as** a number*. And I included the link in my answer just so that you could check the possible values for the `type` argument.

Comment: Nonetheless, can you edit your post and include the full arguments you used, including the `new WP_Query` part?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Add `var_dump( $loop->request );` after you call `new WP_Query`, and share the output. But your query args look fine to me, so are you sure there are posts in the `atsc_bod` CPT where **both** the meta in question are set in each of those post? Are you also sure the meta keys are correct? How do you set/add the meta; via a plugin (e.g. ACF) or your own code?

Comment: Edited the question to include var_dump.  I had the same thought about both meta being set and they are.  I can sort the output by one or the other and get expected results.  I used ACF for the meta and custom coded the CPT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133592/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-brett).